# Can't bind to ldaps when creating new Domain Controller

Tags: ldap, domain-controller

I'm using ldp.exe..... I can connect fine via ldap to my new domain controller by doing this (the Server Name here is a dns alias pointing to the IP of the server)

[image]

[image]

.....***but*** when I attempt to bind using the credentials that *I am actually currently logged into* the new domain controller with ......like this.....

[image]

....it actually gives me the following error (btw, my username and password are correct and not locked or expired or anything)

[image]

Has anybody seen this behavior before? Can someone explain it?

Comment: Are you using LDAP o LDAPS? If the second (as the name seems to imply), you should use TCP port 636 and SSL; also, the server must have a valid certificate. Otherwise you are using plain LDAP, and the name is just confusing.

Comment: @Massimo..thanks for getting back to me but I've solved it...it was a Group Policy thing....I'd put the server in the wrong OU...hopes this helps anybody else though